# Rewrite with both slash and no slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a bit of a tricky situation that I'm not sure how to go about finishing.

I have the following code which redirects `mysite.com/i/somelink/` to `mysite.com/view.php?i=somelink`

```
RewriteRule ^/?i/([^/]+)/$ /view.php?i=$1 [L]
```

The issue is, the code above only works when there is a trailing slash at the end of `mysite.com/i/somelink/`

I need it to work both when there is, and is not a slash.

The tricky part is that I'm also trying not to use a separate rule to reduce stress on the system, and the rule needs to be written in such a way that it does not interfere with `mysite.com/i/somelink.ext`, which also exists, and will be embedded in the file (view.php) I'm redirecting too.

I'm probably making it much more complicated than it needs to be, but basically I just need to make the rule above work both with and without trailing slashes.

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?i/([^/]+)/?$ /view.php?i=$1 [L]
```